# SPARQL delete not deleting anything

Tags: sparql, jena

I executed the sparql update

```
delete { ?s ?p ?o }
WHERE { 
?s <http://n1>/<http://n1>+ ?o.
?s <http://n1> ?o 
}
```

on the following model:

```
<http://0> <http://n1> <http://1> .
<http://1> <http://n1> <http://2> .
<http://2> <http://n1> <http://3> .
<http://0> <http://n1> <http://3> .
```

The update should delete the last triple, since there is another path from `http://0` to `http://3`. But it does not delete anything. Do you know why?

Comment: `?p` is not bound in your `WHERE` part. Do `delete { ?s <http://n1> ?o }` - note, it will only delete the single triple `<http://0> <http://n1> <http://3>`

Comment: Yes, that works. Thx!